# Multiple regex matching in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex in python, while the simple cases are a breeze, I am having troubles extracting multiple words from a string using. The string looks like this:

lyne = "|  0x008d | 2345| 0xe54b5b42 | 0520      | 0x02      GREEN| 4        RED   |"

and access the different substrings between the | | using match.group

is there a way to do this...can anyone please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you can't just use `lyne.split('|')` which'll do it, otherwise use `re.split()` with the same thing...

If you really want a regexp (to match/find instead of split), then (stripping out spaces):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\|?\s*(.*?)\s*\|', lyne)
['0x008d', '2345', '0xe54b5b42', '0520', '0x02 GREEN', '4 RED']
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a regex:

```
substrs = [x.strip() for x in lyne.split('|') if x]
```